# Gridview textbox not returning the updated value using Jquery datepicker

Tags: gridview, textbox, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am having ASP GridView and a TextBox column in that

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtStDate" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" CssClass="myDate" Text='<%#   
    DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "StartDate","{0:MM-dd-yyyy}") %>'
</ItemTemplate>
```

and   JQuery code to add datepicker.

```
 $(function() {
    $('.myDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', minDate: 0 });
 });
```

But after I updated the date using datepicker and try to access the updated date in the code

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in gvSample.Rows)
{
   TextBox txtStartDate = row.FindControl("txtStDate") as TextBox
   DateTime startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtStartDate .Text.Replace("-", "/"), new CultureInfo("en-US"));
}
```

I am always getting the old value. I am not getting the date which is updated using Jquery datepicker. How can i get the updated value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In serve side, you need to set `ReadOnly="false"` to update.

Therefore, set `ReadOnly="true"` by jQuery code.

```
 $(function() {
    $('.myDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy', minDate: 0 })
                .attr('readonly',true);
 });
```

Comment: Thanks Jumpei... It is working fine... How can I restrict the user to enter the value in this textbox ?

Comment: Use the jQuery code above. You set the textbox `ReadOnly="true"` on server side it can't update, but if client side, it's ok.